# TypeInitializationException when instantiating XLWorkbook

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, closedxml

The command `XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();` throws a TypeInitializationException.
Interestingly in another program it worked without problems but in the current one I get the exception.

Version is: 0.69.1.0
Runtime version: v4.0.30319

The references in this one program are:

- ClosedXML
- Microsoft.CSharp
- System
- System.Core
- System.Data
- System.Data.DataSetExceptions
- System.Deployment
- System.Runtime.Serialization
- System.Xml
- System.Xml.Linq
- System.Xml.Serialization

for the Code:

```
DataTable datenTabelle = GetMyData();
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.AddWorksheet(datenTabelle);
worksheet.Cells("A2:A" + (datenTabelle.Rows.Count + 1).ToString()).DataType = XLCellValues.Text;
worksheet.Cells("B2:B" + (datenTabelle.Rows.Count + 1).ToString()).DataType = XLCellValues.Text;
worksheet.Cells("C2:C" + (datenTabelle.Rows.Count + 1).ToString()).DataType = XLCellValues.Text;
worksheet.Cells("D2:D" + (datenTabelle.Rows.Count + 1).ToString()).DataType = XLCellValues.DateTime;
worksheet.Cells("E2:E" + (datenTabelle.Rows.Count + 1).ToString()).DataType = XLCellValues.Text;
worksheet.Cells("F2:F" + (datenTabelle.Rows.Count + 1).ToString()).DataType = XLCellValues.Text;
worksheet.Cells("G2:G" + (datenTabelle.Rows.Count + 1).ToString()).DataType = XLCellValues.Number;
worksheet.Cells("H2:H" + (datenTabelle.Rows.Count + 1).ToString()).DataType = XLCellValues.Number;
worksheet.Cells("I2:I" + (datenTabelle.Rows.Count + 1).ToString()).DataType = XLCellValues.Number;
```

Edit as some info: I already tried to eliminate the DataTable line and made the XLWorkbook line the first one executed by the program but still the same problem.

I'm a bit out of ideas there as to what could cause this exception here?

Comment: can you share the related code section?

Comment: sure added it but it is always only as soon as the new XLWorkbook comand is reached.

Comment: I suspect the problem is related with GetMyData() function, can you share the related code section?

Comment: @daryal don't think so (will update the question with this info also): I eliminated the GetMyData and just used  the XLWorkbook line as the first line in the program and it still had the same problem.

Comment: Generally, TypeInitialization exception is a sign of having a field null in the constructor. Do you have excel installed?

Comment: @daryal yes a complete office (2013) is installed. And like I mentioned in another program with the same references it works without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using ClosedXML you need to reference the **Microsoft OpenXML SDK** (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll).

Comment: Will try that out on monday. One quesiton though could there be any reason for the documentFormat.OpenXml not needed to be referenced? (as I checked the other program which works and never saw a refrence to that there)

Comment: No, ClosedXML should not work without that reference. Maybe you overlooked it.

Comment: Managed to test it already. Seeminlgy the openxml was in another subproject of the other program and that was the problem. tnx

Answer (score 0):

Check [Nuget Site> Dependency](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/0.69.1#dependencies-body-tab)

There is only one dependency for this version [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/)

There are lot of change with change in version of OpenXML.

SO with the [version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/0.96.0#versions-body-tab) of ClosedXML the dependency changes.

Note: Use it wisely, or you will require to code again if you change version, so match existing version and fix it.